# Which jar do I need to use Spring AOP AspectJ Annotation?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm new to Spring. 
I am trying to use Spring AOP annotation like the following code.

```
@Aspect
public class A {
    @Pointcut("execution(* Operation.*(..))")
    public void b(){} 

    @Before("b()") 
    public void c(JoinPoint jp)
    {
        System.out.println("a");
    }
}
```

In my referenced libraries, I put all the spring jar **(aop, core, aspects , beans, context, instrument, jdbc,jms,web, webmvc, etc)**

I found another jar **aspectj-1.9.3.jar** and added it to my libraries in my **eclipse**. However, I can't import `org.aspectj.lang.*` (which I need). My Eclipse doesn't seem to locate it.

Did I find the right jar? (so the problem is something else?)
Or do I need another jar? I am trying to do it without using **Maven**.

Comment: Does that **aspectj-1.9.3.jar** has `org.aspectj.lang.*` ?

Comment: Oh, it has **aspectj-1.9.3.jar\files\lib\aspectjrt.jar\org\aspectj\lang**. Maybe, because you've already import the same package from other library so Eclipse doesn't see difference?

Comment: @Dred  I downloaded that from Eclipse foundation site. I wasn't sure if I got the right one, or I need some extra jar.  aspectj-1.9.3 supposed to work?

Comment: I downloaded it too. Any error or warnigs from Eclipse ?

Comment: @Dred  I just have a red line in my Eclipse. I refreshed it, but Eclipse doesn't seem to notice it.

Comment: @Dred thank you for your tips. Have a good day~

Comment: @Dred I've downloaded a jar from a place mentioned below and downloaded aspectjtools-1.8.9.jar and it works!

Comment: It's a good news) Have a good day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
org.aspectj.lang.joinpoint is part of the aspectj tool library.
```

Add this to the Maven :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as I wrote, I am trying to avoid using Maven. Could you add some link where I can download that jar?

Comment: Yup!! https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjtools/1.8.9. Download jar from there

Comment: I didn't know I can download jar from there. I thought I can only get dependency from that site. I am looking at the page right now. And I have one more dumb question. I can find any button to download :(

Comment: You can find almost any published jars at https://search.maven.org/ or https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter these are the 2 main central repositories. They are the standard places Maven or Gradle use to download dependencies.

Comment: @Anish B. I found the button. Sorry about that. haha.. Now I know!! thank you

Comment: [that] (http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/aspectj/aspectjtools/1.9.2/aspectjtools-1.9.2.jar)  link works. But will it help you

Comment: _aspectjtools_ is too fat and unnecessary, you only need it if you want to use the AspectJ compiler from within your code. The OP doesn't even use full AspectJ, only Spring AOP. So _aspectjrt_ should be enough. Even for full AspectJ with load-time weaving (LTW) you only need _aspectjweaver_ which is a superset of _aspectjrt_ and a subset of _aspectjtools_. If _aspectjrt_ does not work, you are making a mistake. Maybe you forgot to add the library to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Below i have mentioned the Lightweight jars as `aspectjtools` is too big.

```
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aop', version: '5.1.5.RELEASE'
compile group: 'aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.5.4'
```

Size of jars:

```
aspectjtools 1.9.2: 13.2 MB // too big
```

And

```
 aspectjweaver 1.9.2: 2.0 MB,  // too small as compared to aspectjtools jar
 spring AOP 5.1.5: 360 KB
```

So, avoid using aspectjtools jar as it is too big.

Comment: thank you for your good information. so aspectjweaver & spring AOP can replace aspectjtools?

Comment: Yes, for implementing Spring AOP you can replace it